# How to link references to url in bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, urls, jabref

I have BibTex citations [taken from ADS](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/doi/10.1086/177181) which look like this:

```
@ARTICLE{1996ApJ...462..672T,
  author = {{Tolstoy}, E. and {Saha}, A.},
   title = "{The Interpretation of Color-Magnitude Diagrams through Numerical Simulation and Bayesian Inference}",
 journal = {\apj},
keywords = {STARS: HERTZSPRUNG-RUSSELL DIAGRAM, METHODS: STATISTICAL},
    year = 1996,
   month = may,
  volume = 462,
   pages = {672},
     doi = {10.1086/177181},
  adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1996ApJ...462..672T},
 adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```

This looks like this in the Bibliography:

Tolstoy, E. y Saha, A. The Interprettion of Color-Magnitude Diagrams
through Numerical Simulation and Bayesian Inference. *The Astrophysical
Journal*, vol. 462, página 672, 1996.

What I would like is for that reference to take me to the url specified in the field **adsurl** when clicked on the title or maybe even the whole reference. Is this possible?

I use JabRef by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you are using (a) a bibliography style file that knows what to do with a field named `url` in an entry of type `@article` and (b) the `natbib` citation management package, all you would have to do is (i) change the name of the field from `adsurl` to `url` and (ii) load the `hyperref` package.

After some poking around on the web, I've come across the bibliography style [apj_hyperrefstyle](http://cosmologist.info/utils/apj_hyperref.bst) which purports to know how to process fields named `adsurl`; however, I have no idea if that file meets your other reference formatting needs.